# Finding inorder successor

Tags: java, tree

I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple. This code finds inorder successor in a binary tree.

```
public class Successor {

    private TreeNode root;

    private class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode parent;
        int item;

        TreeNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right, TreeNode parent, int item) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    public void makeBinarySearchTree(int[] a) {
        for (int i : a) {
            addElement(i);
        }
    }

    public void addElement(int element) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(null, null, null, element);
        } else {
            TreeNode prevNode = null;
            TreeNode node = root;

            while (node != null) {
                prevNode = node;
                // no definition exists, and for convenience we will stick to this one.
                if (element < node.item) {
                    node = node.left;
                } else {
                    node = node.right;
                }
            }

            if (element < prevNode.item) {
                prevNode.left = new TreeNode(null, null, prevNode, element);
            } else {
                prevNode.right = new TreeNode(null, null, prevNode, element);
            }
        }
    }

    private TreeNode search (int x) {
        TreeNode node = root;

        while (node != null) {
            if (x < node.item) {
                node = node.left;
            } else if (x  > node.item) {
                node = node.right;
            } else {
               return node;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


    public Integer getSucessor(int val) {
        TreeNode node = getInorderSuccessor(search(val));
        return node == null ? null : node.item; 
    }


    private TreeNode getInorderSuccessor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return null;

        if (node.right != null) {
            node = node.right;
            while (node.left != null) {
                node = node.left;
            }
            return node;
        } else {
            while (node.parent != null && node == node.parent.right) {
                node = node.parent;
            }
            return node.parent;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I assume that this is Java, given your Username? I added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please give clear meaningful name. Your class name is `Successor`... now who's successor? yours? king Luthar's? who's? See the concern. I think `BinarySearchTree` is the apt. name for the class.
- In `makeBinarySearchTree` you are creating a Binary Tree, so someone seeing your code will think it as a *factory method*, so better make it that way.
- You can make your class generic but that's not a big deal for now but in future keep this in head and try to find always general solution for any given problem.
- Someone using your `getSucessor` method(should be `getSuccessor`) will always get the inorder-successor. Now what if someday someone want to find preorder-successor or preorder-successor, what will you do then?

Otherwise your code is good and self-documenting.